# AngularJS accessing self vs this do not have $$hashKey

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that binds to an object, and inside it's template access my object like:

```
return {
    template: '<span>{{myObj.imageFile}}</span> <br/>'
             +'<span>{{myObj.imageUrl()}}</span> <br />'
};
```

I noted that the first span showed my property correctly, but the second do not get updated after I changed `imageFile` property

```
function (section, type, sizeX, sizeY) {
    var self = { /* Other properties */ };

    self.imageUrl = function () {

        var imgUrl = '/Images/no_image.jpg'

        if (self.imageFile != null) { // works if changed to this
            imgUrl = '/Images/' + self.imageFile; // works if changed to this
        }

        return imgUrl;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Debugging, I noticed that if I use `this` instead of `self`, the code works properly. Displaying the variables content in chrome console I noted that while accessing using `this`, the object contains a property `$$hashKey`, and via `self` the object contains not. I know `$$hashKey` is used to track the object. But why `self`, that represents the same object do not have it as a property?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure of what's going on but the use of self is not advised since there's a global self (window.self) that represents the window. As for why it doesn't have $$hashKey while it does seem to have all the other properties.. no freaking idea.

Comment: look to prototype chain, I'm almost sure 'this' is poiting to an another object that has "self" as its prototype.

Comment: I can only guess because your example isn't a complete one. I guess  the `function (section, type, sizeX, sizeY)` is placed within a controller. But then I don't know why you are returning the self object. This would argue for an service. Please give some details or create a plunker. If you are using the controllerAs syntax `this` could be the scope of the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observed error and code was misleading. The issue was that when loading the page, I create a clone of the object as:

```
var defaultObject = myConstructorFunction(/* parameters */);

angular.merge(defaultObject, obj);

return defaultObject;
```

So, `self` was referencing the original object, and I was overriding all of it using `angular.merge` function. Also, this function does not copy the the `$hashKey$`